# Get Count of Rows that is group by in sql

Tags: php, sql, join, group-by, left-join

My sql query is getting data from sql table.here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` bo 
LEFT JOIN routes ro ON bo.iRouteId = ro.iRouteId 
LEFT JOIN buses bu ON bo.iBusId = bu.iBusId 
WHERE eBookingBy = 'User' AND iUserId = '2' 
ORDER BY bo.iBookingId DESC
```

Now this will return me o/p like this

[image]
that means it returns me two data with having same booking id,now what i want is to do `GROUP BY bo.vBookingNo` Soo it wiill returns me only one data.

Now what i need is i need an count of **How many rows were group by**.

For example if i use group by `vBookingNo` in above query than it will o/p me only one result. but it also returns me an count of rows that is group by.

so here it will return o/p Count 2.

Thanks.

Comment: _that means it returns me two data with having same booking id,now what i want is to do GROUP BY bo.vBookingNo Soo it wiill returns me only one data._ Can you clarify this part?

Comment: Use `count(*)`.

Comment: When I didn't use GROUP_BY than it will return me two data as per where condition but if I use group by so definitely it will return me one data.so what  i need is only count of that group by data

Comment: My bad, I misread but the answer from Zaynul is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need count()

```
SELECT vBookingNo, count(*) FROM `bookings` bo 
LEFT JOIN routes ro ON bo.iRouteId = ro.iRouteId 
LEFT JOIN buses bu ON bo.iBusId = bu.iBusId 
WHERE eBookingBy = 'User' AND iUserId = '2' 
group by vBookingNo
```

Comment: its really great.i searched and tried a lot but not think  about count(*).as i am assuming count(*) will produce count of all data.Very Good :)